# How to combine FullCalendar and Ajax to save objects to the database in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery, fullcalendar

I am just now learning MVC for web development. My ultimate goal is to make it so you can create appointments by clicking on a timeslot within FullCalendar and it save to the database. I've managed to get FullCalendar up, and a modal that pop-ups and I've put a ajax "savemyobjects" id as a button but I can't figure out how to save the data inputted into the modal into the calendar to the database.

I just need some direction really. I have the components: ajax, modals, and FullCalendar but I need to learn how to use them together effectively. I've researched a little on FullCalendar's site for the eventtriggers but not sure if that is what I need or not.

Thanks for any input/suggestions/help

Answer (score 0):

Use the renderEvent method as specified in the documentation(http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/) to render the newly added event. But before calling the renderEvent method use the $.ajax method of jquery to post your event information to a server side controller method and save the event information to the database. If any error occurs display a user friendly error and stop rendering the event.

Comment: Thank you! I sort of know how to render events. I just don't know how to translate a rendered event into an object that can be saved in a database.